# How to source a file in puppet manifest from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, manifest, puppet, vagrant

I am trying to source files from local modules in a puppet manifest (using puppet in standalone mode):

```ruby
file {
  '/home/repowt/.crontab':
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/site/crontab';
}
```

but I get:

```
Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from source(s) ...
```

The file is in:

```
config/puppet/modules/site/files/crontab
```

(puppet is called via `vagrant provision` and the Vagrantfile specifies module_path='config/puppet/modules' and is clearly ok since puppet does load modules with import from there.)

I also tried:

```ruby
source => 'puppet:///site/crontab'
source => 'site/crontab'
source => 'config/puppet/modules/site/files/crontab'
source => '/modules/site/crontab'
```

of no avail. I found nothing illuminating on the web, seems like something very simple.
your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, as pwan notes, the `fileserver.conf` needs to be setup correctly.

Keeping in mind that `/vagrant` contains the directory where `Vagrantfile` is (and therefore all of it content), that meant for me doing:

```
vm_config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "modules", :options => ["--fileserverconfig=/vagrant/fileserver.conf", ]
```

My `fileserver.conf` specifies that `/etc/puppet/files` is to be used.

Whilst I could have specified a different `fileserver.conf`, just for Vagrant, I wanted pretty much everything to be the same as normal.

So, I also mounted `/etc/puppet/files` too, with

```
vm_config.vm.share_folder "files", "/etc/puppet/files", "files"
```

Which got things working for me.

Comment: Also this could probably also be tagged with [tag:vagrant]

Comment: Docs for vm.share_folder : http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html

Comment: better late than never to accept. i abandonned this but nice answer.

Comment: Because [symlinks dont always work](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/713) hence I wasn't able to set 'files' symlink in my VagrantBox-OS-Virtualizer combination. Due to this, I was never able to access things from `puppet:///` path

Answer (score 12):

`puppet:///modules/my_module/file` should match `%vagrant_root%/modules/my_module/files/file`

Comment: This comment helped me fix my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that Vagrant mounted a copy of its dir on the target VM (I'm using base http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15307300/vagrant-0.7-centos-64-base.box); do a "mount" and see if you have this too.

This allows me to create a directory within my Vagrant, parallel to manifests/ that I call "files/". I then put my config  source file under there, e.g., .../myvagrantproject/files/slapd.conf.  This appears on the VM as /vagrant/files/slapd.conf

Then in the puppet manifest for the file source I list the source as an absolute file path, not a puppet server path, like:

```
file { 'slapd.conf':
  name          => '/etc/openldap/slapd.conf',
  ensure        => present,
  source        => '/vagrant/files/slapd.conf',
  owner         => root,
  group         => ldap,
  mode          => 0640,
  require       => Package["ldapservers"],
}
```

It found it no problemmo from it's own vbox-mounted remote filesystem.

Comment: yes, thanks, thought of this, but it's cheating. I want to source it from a module on the fs i call vagrant from.

Answer (score 3):

Your original puppet://modules/site/crontab should work.

I suspect the fileserver.conf on your puppetmaster may not have a modules section.  Try adding something like below if it's not already present.

```
[modules]
    allow *
```

Check out the 'Module Lookup' section at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/modules.html

Comment: Also check out the docs for fileserver.conf http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your description if you are using the puppet in standalone mode or in client-server mode.
Assuming that you are using the standalone mode, double check in your /tmp folder in your vm to see if the module folder is actually there and vagrant has mounted it.
The fact that you can load the manifest, doesn't mean that the modules are there as well.

Your original configuration, looks correct.

Comment: standalone yes. edited my post. Even if it is in tmp or mounted elsewhere, the fact is that puppet on the vm does not find it. I really wonder how this can happen I mean is this not the most basic feature of it to put files from here to there.... grr